# FontAwsome and Text Alignment

Tags: font-awesome, text-alignment

So I want to make the fontawsome icon and the text align so the icon is staying on the left side and all the text is on the right. Please take a look at [what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PLuj.png) and I what [I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXJMv.png).

With mine you can see the second line goes all the way back to the left side. Where the icon is above.

Here is the code of what I have currently:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Place your kit's code here -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/74e8323267.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Ready to use Font Awesome. Activate interlock. Dynotherms - connected. Infracells - up. Icons are go! -->

<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-warning">
    <i class="fas fa-exclamation fa-2x fa-fw"></i>&nbsp;<font size="4"><b>In observation of the holiday, LCS website will not have updated guidance on Friday, April 10, 2020. Guidance and updates will resume Monday, April 13, 2020.</font></b>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update your bootstrap version you could use its flex properties to achieve.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Also wrapping your elements into their own `div` will make it easier for you to manage their spacing.

In case you don't want to update your bootstrap you can write the same with CSS.

```
.wrapping-div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Place your kit's code here -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/74e8323267.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Ready to use Font Awesome. Activate interlock. Dynotherms - connected. Infracells - up. Icons are go! -->

  <div class="container">
    <div class="alert alert-warning d-flex align-items-center">
      <div>
        <i class="fas fa-exclamation fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
      </div>
      <div>
       <font size="4"><b>In observation of the holiday, LCS website will not have updated guidance on Friday, April 10, 2020. Guidance and updates will resume Monday, April 13, 2020.</b></font>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```